# Image Gallery with support names and pics

Tags: java, android

I found this library **"Image Gallery"** and is very useful to my project.
I have two questions for you. If you can help me

the first one is about the files, how can put local files (stored in sd card) in the Arraylist . cause I put a list with local files **("/storage/emulated/0/APP_FILES/2015_09_15_033612.jpg")** but seems not liked.

the second one is about the names of the pictures, if the library support adding names to the pics

This is a part of the Activity code if put **URLS to web image files works** but I need to **use Local Files stored in SD CARD**.
Don´t work , so here is the code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageGalleryActivity.class);

ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

images.add("/storage/emulated/0/APP_FILES/2015_09_15_033612.jpg");
images.add("/storage/emulated/0/APP_FILES/2015_09_15_03213321.jpg");
images.add("/storage/emulated/0/APP_FILES/2015_09_15_01234.jpg");

intent.putStringArrayListExtra("images", images);
// optionally set background color using Palette
intent.putExtra("palette_color_type", PaletteColorType.VIBRANT);

startActivity(intent);
```

the library is 
https://github.com/lawloretienne/ImageGallery
If any one knows about another simple image library to implements names and images please advise me.

thanks in advance

Comment: ... something like [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/a-3d-carousel-view-for-android/)?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial and read the comments for tweeks -- http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Answer (score 0):

The below method gave the answer of your both questions,

You should do like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageGalleryActivity.class);

ArrayList<String> images = getImageList("/storage/emulated/0/APP_FILES/");

intent.putStringArrayListExtra("images", images);
// optionally set background color using Palette
intent.putExtra("palette_color_type", PaletteColorType.VIBRANT);

startActivity(intent);

private ArrayList<String> getImageList(String dirPath)
{
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] listList = new File(path).listFiles();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < listList.length; i++)
    {
        paths.add("file://"+listList[i]);
    }
    return paths;
}
```

Comment: @exequielc , This method will work for your library...!

Comment: My problems is that  I can't adding a name or title to show in gallery. How can I do that?. I don't see how can I do this with your code.

Comment: can you help with this? Don't know where put the name or title to show with the picture  @Arsa Imam

Comment: Yesterday, I dived in the project library but I didn't found the way to set names, you need to edit the library and its custom views...!